# Order a dataframe column by the count of an id

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to count the students and order the students by the counts and print the top 3.
I tried it with:

```
df['freq'] = df.groupby('studentid')['studentid'].transform('count')
df.sort_values('freq')
print("The 3 students")
print(df[['freq', 'studentname', 'studentid']])
```

But the output is every time the same.
The output only shows me the normal data frame with the frequency, but doesn't sort it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`df.sort_values('freq')` returns a (sorted) copy of the data. So:

```
df = df.sort_values('freq')
```

or

```
df.sort_values('freq', inplace=True)
```

Comment: Is the same thing with `df['freq'] = df.groupby('studentid')['studentid'].transform('count')`.? He also didn't grouped it.